# Creating view using Index results in "plugin does not exist"

Tags: views, 8, search

I was having some problems with Search API after adding my second index (using DB not Solr).  The index I was trying to create was supposed to just be the body and title of a content type.  I was able to build the index just fine, but when trying to attach it to a view (My Test View) I'm getting a funky message directly above the Preview section on the view page.

> The "views_page:my_test_view__page_1" plugin does not exist.

I am utterly confused by this.  I uninstalled Search API and reinstalled, but the only change is this now happens to both views using a search index.  I am able to successfully create non-search index views, but that's the only evidence I have this is even Search API's problem.  Can someone please direct me on how to start debugging this?

This is Drupal 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now believe this is some type of caching issue, though I'm not sure why.  Originally I thought uninstalling a particular module fixed the issue, but the "plugin does not exist" error appeared the next day when creating a new view. Clearing the cache seems to clear the error, which is a good enough workaround for now until I have more time to dedicate to this.

Answer (score 0):

It is weird try to add on your view configuration file in the context section the following lines:

```
  contexts:
    - 'languages:language_content'
    - 'languages:language_interface'
    - url.query_args
    - user.permissions
```

It seems like when you export the configuration the last two lines are missing.